# macVim: line continuation in python creates unnecessary tab?

Tags: python, vim, macvim

Whenever I want to use line continuation in my python script using macVim, I receive the following format:

```
a = one,\
        two,\
        three
```

instead of:

```
a = one,\
    two,\
    three
```

I've rifled through `help`, and was unable to locate what exactly is causing macVim to append an extra tab upon using line continuation.

Note: I currently have the following in my .vimrc file:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
```

Comment: The `vim-python-pep8` plugin is quite good at doing indentation that conforms to PEP8, I'm not sure about this specific case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings are almost fine. In Python code, the tab settings should *always* be

```
:set tabstop=8 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab
```

These settings honour the recommendations in the "Style guide for Python code" known as **[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)** and are universally followed in Python code. Stick to these settings, or even better, set up an autocommand that sets them automatically. In your vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal ts=8 sw=4 sts=4 et
```

Now on to your problem: This is caused by the default indentation rules in Vim's indent script for Python. Fortunately, these rules can be customised. In your case you just need to put the following line in your vimrc.

```
let g:pyindent_continue = '&shiftwidth'
```

(In newer versions of Vim, use `'shiftwidth()'` instead of  `'&shiftwidth'`.)

For more information, look up [`:h ft-python-indent`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#ft-python-indent).

Answer (score 2):

You have your tabs set to 4 and not 2

Make sure that you have

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

You can also use something as followed in your .vimrc as a oneliner for defaults instead of adding them on separate lines

Use 2 instead of 4

```
set ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 noexpandtab
```

Comment: This is very bad advice for Python. [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) recommends indenting with four spaces and this recommendation is universally followed in Python code.